# What is the best way to use multi language field titles, stored in MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I store in a MySQL table "menuLang" for different languages the correct titles for fields or menu items.

As a sample:

```
language = 1,text[1] = "Welcome",text[2] = "Good bye"
language = 2,text[1] = "Willkommen",text[2] = "Auf Wiedersehen"
```

I want to have in the program code for outputs a variable (text) depending on the language.

The user should have the option to change the whole webpage with a mouse click on a flag button.

I am not sure what is fast, does not cost to many resources and is efficient.

I have no idea about the general way how to do it. I checked the internet and did not find good answers.

Comment: You may want to look at `gettext`

Comment: Great Tip. I downloaded it already.

To all the people who help this best page for programming questions to be at this quality a happy new year! 

What you are doing is outstanding.

Sorry to the SysOps, this is off topic, but it was time to say it!

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested you look at the [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)  / [`poedit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poedit) system for localization. That is a good suggestion.

If you will definitely do this with MySQL, it looks like you need a table like this:

```
language_id    message_id     message_text
    1             1           Welcome
    2             1           Bienvenue
    3             1           Wilkommen
    1             2           See you later
    2             2           Au revoir
    3             2           Auf Wiedersehen
    1             3           File not found
```

You may also need a "language choice" attribute for each of your users. For example, you might have a column called `language_id` in your `user` table.

Finally, if your localization effort is like most of them in the real world, you'll have one language that's complete, and the others will have some missing entries. See the last row in my example. The default language has `language_id = 1` in my example.

Then, when you need the text of a message, you'll know the `message_id` and `user_id`. You can do this query to find the text.

```
 SELECT generic.message_id,
        COALESCE(local.message_text,generic.message_text) message_text
   FROM message generic
   LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT message_text, message_id, user_id
              FROM user
              LEFT JOIN message ON message.language_id = user.language_id
             ) local ON generic.message_id = local.message_id
                    AND local.user_id = ???user_id???
 WHERE generic.language_id = 1
   AND generic.message_id = ???message_id??
```

The `COALESCE()` function takes the localized message if it exists, and the generic one if it doesn't.

**EDIT**: (Defect in query fixed.) You can also use the edited query, omitting the line

```
   AND generic.message_id = ???message_id???
```

to get a table with all the messages, localized if possible. Here's a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37e2e/2/0

Comment: Ollie, that is now really funny.

You used exact the field names that I used in the MySQL table. How you knew this? I set it exact up as you said.

Comment: People with superpowers don't talk about superpowers! Happy 2016!

Comment: Ollie, with your idea: But how do I do it that I dont have to include in every file this code? 

My idea was to just load once the data from the DB and make it global readable, but I was reading that it is not the best to do it this way.

Is there any way like this:

<button name="sign_up">Sign Up</button>

But in this way:

<button name="sign_up">menuText[7]</button>

as place holder?