# MySQL select rows of a specific language, or "international" language as fallback

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table of documents. They have a subject, a type, a language, and a filename.
I want to select all the documents about a given subject (any type) in a given language.
The trick is : for the wanted subject and a given type, if the document is not found in the wanted language, I want the missing row to be filled with the "international" language instead.

Example :

```
| subject | type       | lang          | filename                  |
|---------+------------+---------------+---------------------------|
| flowers | cover      | international | flowers_image.jpg         |
| flowers | intro      | en            | flowers_intro_en.pdf      |
| flowers | intro      | fr            | flowers_intro_fr.pdf      |
| flowers | part_1     | en            | flowers_part_1_en.pdf     |
| flowers | part_1     | fr            | flowers_part_1_fr.pdf     |
| flowers | part_2     | en            | flowers_part_2_en.pdf     |
| flowers | part_2     | fr            | flowers_part_2_fr.pdf     |
| flowers | conclusion | en            | flowers_conclusion_en.pdf |
| flowers | conclusion | fr            | flowers_conclusion_fr.pdf |
```

I need a query to select all documents talking about flowers, in english (or international if english not existing).
The expected result would be :

```
| subject | type       | lang          | filename                  |
|---------+------------+---------------+---------------------------|
| flowers | cover      | international | flowers_image.jpg         |
| flowers | intro      | en            | flowers_intro_en.pdf      |
| flowers | part_1     | en            | flowers_part_1_en.pdf     |
| flowers | part_2     | en            | flowers_part_2_en.pdf     |
| flowers | conclusion | en            | flowers_conclusion_en.pdf |
```

Thank you !

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546405/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-multi-language-field-titles-stored-in-mysql/34546902#34546902 help?

Comment: Thank you @O.Jones, looks like COALESCE usage + a left join to a subquery  is a good lead. I will try it !